# Is there any simple way to get a small bit of text from a web browser to a Windows program?

Tags: windows, html

I have a situation where someone gets a code (like a license code string).
They then need to enter that in a Windows program.

I'd like to avoid that second step by maybe having the browser store it someplace that a Windows program would have access to.

**Clarification:**

I'm using .ASPX on the server side.
On the client side, I can use .js in the browser and  I'm using VB6 and the Wise Installer (could "retrieve" the bit of text using either). I want to support all major browsers (although this solution doesn't need to work for 100%of cases:  if we can get the code entered *for* the customer in 80% of cases, that's a huge improvement.

Any ideas?

Comment: framework? limitations? Not much to go on since there are a number of ways to accomplish this based on what you can and can not do.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the data in the Windows clipboard; although it's tricky to put things on the clipboard from a web page, it is still possible (often with a Flash helper).

Another approach is to embed a web browser control *inside* your app, where your app has full control over the user interactions. The app can then intercept the relevant data as it comes back from the server.